# Parsing json data from while loop

Tags: php, android, json

I am working on a little project for school and for this project i need to parse data from a database that is encoded into json. Now i have been succesfull to encode just one object but not all that are being retrieved.

Code to transfer one object:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener2 = new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(response);
        Log.i("HIAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", response);
        boolean tweet_success = jsonObject2.getBoolean("tweet_succes");
        String tweet_sendbyuser = jsonObject2.getString("tweet_send_by_user");
        String tweet_description = jsonObject2.getString("tweet_description");
        String tweet_favourites = jsonObject2.getString("tweet_favourites");
        String tweet_retweets = jsonObject2.getString("tweet_retweets");
        String tweet_reactions = jsonObject2.getString("tweet_reactions");
        boolean tweet_isReaction = jsonObject2.getBoolean("tweet_isReaction");
        String tweet_reactedTo = jsonObject2.getString("tweet_reactedTo");
        String tweet_dateSend = jsonObject2.getString("tweet_dateSend");
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet(tweet_sendbyuser, tweet_description, tweet_favourites, tweet_retweets, tweet_reactions, tweet_isReaction, tweet_reactedTo);
        LoggedInDetails.getInstance().addTweet(tweet);
        if (tweet_success) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Parsing done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", LoggedInDetails.getInstance().getUsername());
            intent.putExtra("password", LoggedInDetails.getInstance().getPassword());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error during parsing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("", response);
    }
}};
```

Then there is the code i made to have it parse all data returned. However what this does is create 11 seperate objects from the first row and still not do anything with the second or whatever row:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener2 = new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response.trim());
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
        boolean tweet_success = false;
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            Log.i("HIAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", response);
            tweet_success = jObject.getBoolean("tweet_succes");
            String tweet_sendbyuser = jObject.getString("tweet_send_by_user");
            String tweet_description = jObject.getString("tweet_description");
            String tweet_favourites = jObject.getString("tweet_favourites");
            String tweet_retweets = jObject.getString("tweet_retweets");
            String tweet_reactions = jObject.getString("tweet_reactions");
            boolean tweet_isReaction = jObject.getBoolean("tweet_isReaction");
            String tweet_reactedTo = jObject.getString("tweet_reactedTo");
            String tweet_dateSend = jObject.getString("tweet_dateSend");
            Tweet tweet = new Tweet(tweet_sendbyuser, tweet_description, tweet_favourites, tweet_retweets, tweet_reactions, tweet_isReaction, tweet_reactedTo);
            LoggedInDetails.getInstance().addTweet(tweet);

        }if (tweet_success) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Parsing done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", LoggedInDetails.getInstance().getUsername());
            intent.putExtra("password", LoggedInDetails.getInstance().getPassword());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error during parsing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("", response);
    }
}};
```

Then there is my collect_tweet.php (important part only)

```
if($fetch_tweets->execute()){
        $response1 = array();
        $response1["tweet_succes"] = false;
        while($row = $fetch_tweets->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $response1["tweet_succes"] = true;
            $response1["succes"] = true;
            $response1["tweet_id"] = $row["tweet_id"];
            $response1["tweet_send_by_user"] = $row['tweet_sendbyuser'];
            $response1["tweet_description"] = $row['tweet_description'];
            $response1["tweet_favourites"] = $row['tweet_favourites'];
            $response1["tweet_retweets"] = $row['tweet_retweets'];
            $response1["tweet_reactions"] = $row['tweet_reactions'];
            $response1["tweet_isReaction"] = $row['tweet_isReaction'];
            $response1["tweet_reactedTo"] = $row['tweet_reactedTo'];
            $response1["tweet_dateSend"] = $row['tweet_dateSend'];
            echo json_encode($response1);
        }
    }else{
        $response1["tweet_succes"] = false;
        echo json_encode($response1);
    }
```

Part of the JSON that im currently getting in a browser: (dummy test data)

```
{
    "tweet_succes":true,
    "succes":true,
    "tweet_id":"1",
    "tweet_send_by_user":"1",
    "tweet_description":"Ja ik weet niet zo goed wat de eerste tweet moest zijn, dus dit is em maar he",
    "tweet_favourites":"2, 3, 4",
    "tweet_retweets":"2, 3, 4",
    "tweet_reactions":"",
    "tweet_isReaction":"false",
    "tweet_reactedTo":"-1",
    "tweet_dateSend":"2016-04-23 23:39:49"
}
{
    "tweet_succes":true,
    "succes":true,
    "tweet_id":"2",
    "tweet_send_by_user":"2",
    "tweet_description":"Ja ik weet niet zo goed wat de eerste tweet moest zijn, dus dit is em maar he",
    "tweet_favourites":"2, 3, 4",
    "tweet_retweets":"2, 3, 4",
    "tweet_reactions":"",
    "tweet_isReaction":"false",
    "tweet_reactedTo":"-1",
    "tweet_dateSend":"2016-04-23 23:40:49"
}
```

I am probably parsing it wrong or i need to use JSONArray instead of object.

My objective is to make tweets based on the data that i am receiving.

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

You are returning multiple single arrays instead of building an array of arrays and returning it all in one go.

This will build all the data into one reply

```
$response1 = array();
$response1["tweet_succes"] = false;
if($fetch_tweets->execute()){
    $response1["tweet_succes"] = true;
    $response1["succes"] = true;

    while($row = $fetch_tweets->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $t = array();
        $t["tweet_id"] = $row["tweet_id"];
        $t["tweet_send_by_user"] = $row['tweet_sendbyuser'];
        $t["tweet_description"] = $row['tweet_description'];
        $t["tweet_favourites"] = $row['tweet_favourites'];
        $t["tweet_retweets"] = $row['tweet_retweets'];
        $t["tweet_reactions"] = $row['tweet_reactions'];
        $t["tweet_isReaction"] = $row['tweet_isReaction'];
        $t["tweet_reactedTo"] = $row['tweet_reactedTo'];
        $t["tweet_dateSend"] = $row['tweet_dateSend'];
        $response1[] = $t;
    }
}else{
    $response1["tweet_succes"] = false;
}

echo json_encode($response1);  // finally return the complete array
```

It could also be done even more simply, if you query only SELECT's these fields and no other then you can write

```
$response1 = array();
$response1["tweet_succes"] = false;
if($fetch_tweets->execute()){
    $response1["tweet_succes"] = true;
    $response1['results'] = $fetch_tweets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
}else{
    $response1["tweet_succes"] = false;
}

echo json_encode($response1);  // finally return the complete array
```